# Matlab 2009b & .NET

Tags: .net, matlab, enums

I am having all sort of trouble with [FlagsAttribute] enums in Matlab.
It appears there is no way to pass a combination of values as a parameter to .NET.
For example, BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance, once you combine these together in Matlab they become of an internal type and cannot be cast back to BindingFlags.

Things like

```
import System.*;
import System.Reflection.*;

flags = BindingFlags.Public+BindingFlags.Instance;
enum  = Enum.ToObject(Type.GetType('System.Reflection.BindingFlags'), int32(flags));
```

or

```
enum = Enum.Parse(Type.GetType('System.Reflection.BindingFlags'), 'Public, Instance');
```

simply don't work as it reads:

??? One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "System.Enum.ToObject" 
(or "System.Enum.Parse").

On the other hand

```
enum = Enum.Parse(Type.GetType('System.Reflection.BindingFlags'), 'Public');
```

works just fine and returns <1x1 System.Reflection.BindingFlags> set to 'Public'.

That goes, needless to say, for all [FlagsAttribute] enums.

Am I missing something here?
Writing a C# reflection enum wrapper for Matlab is not a big deal but that would slow things down enormously.
Any workaround would be deeply, deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AN ANSWER TO THE WRONG QUESTION:

If I understand the problem correctly it is this:

To pass enums to MATLAB, you need to convert it to a variable type that MATLAB understands – in this case a string.  So your enum

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
```

gets converted to

```
"Public, Instance"  // via flags.ToString()
```

When the code comes back to .NET from MATLAB, you want to convert the string back to being an enum.

You were very close, and the example on the [help page for Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) gives you the syntax.

```
BindingFlags flags2 = (BindingFlags)Enum.Parse(typeof(BindingFlags), "Public, Instance");
```

(Also, naming a variable "enum" is only going to end in tears.)

---

A SECOND ATTEMPT AT AN ANSWER

I agree that this MATLAB behaviour seems broken.  One solution would be to write your own wrappers to `Enum.Parse` and `Enum.Object`, that don't break.  Something like these:

```
function enum = EnumParse(typename, value)
import System.*;

type = Type.GetType(typename);
values = regexp(value, ', ', 'split');

enum = cell(1, length(values));
for i = 1:length(values)
   enum{i} = Enum.Parse(type, values{i});
end
end


function enum = EnumToObject(typename, value)
import System.*;

type = Type.GetType(typename);
values = int32(GetPowersOf2(value));

enum = cell(1, length(values));
for i = 1:length(values)
   enum{i} = Enum.ToObject(type, values(i));
end
end

function y = GetPowersOf2(x)
index = logical(arrayfun(@str2num, dec2bin(x)));
y = 2.^((length(index) - 1):-1:0);
y = y(index);
end
```

Usage of these is, e.g.,

```
EnumParse('System.Reflection.BindingFlags', 'Public, Instance')
EnumToObject('System.Reflection.BindingFlags', 20)
```

Note that I've taken the easy route here and just returned a cell array of BindingFlags, rather than trying to persuade MATLAB to combine them again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not how I described the problem. All your code is in C#. All my code is in Matlab (that is why naming a variable "enum" is completely legit). So, please, read my question carefully. There is no water in it. Appreciate your input anyway.

Comment: Oh, yes, and thank you for properly formatting my question in the first place. I hope once you take a second look you are able to help me out.

Comment: Oh well. Second attempt. "EnumToObject" function creates and returns cell array of enums but fails to accomplish the task in question: setting an enum object to a value "20" or whatever else combination of flags (as opposed to single flag, like "Public") from Matlab.

Comment: "EnumParse" is meaningless because we cannot get the the string "Public, Instance" from anywhere but make it up ourselves! Matlab just won't return the [FlagsAttribute] enums set to a combination of values. It gives us <0x0 System.Reflection.BindingFlags> instead.
And there is no need to parse our own string...
I think it's about time we drop this question until the next release comes out.
Now, I want to thank you for your time and efforts spent. Appreciate it.

Comment: "Until the next release comes out" was sadly too optimistic. I'm working with MATLAB 2010b, and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't an answer, just more information)

At the time of writing, the latest version of MATLAB(2010b) does not provide a .NET interface that lets you work with flag enumerations.

One of the fundamental pieces of .NET that MATLAB does not support is casting. 
This means a line of code like this:

```
myControl.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)(AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom)
```

Cannot be written in MATLAB.

The .NET method *System.Enum.Parse* would be ideal for solving the problem of creating combined flags enumerations in MATLAB. But, when invoked from MATLAB, System.Enum.Parse is broken.

Try this:

```
>> NET.addAssembly('System.Windows.Forms');
>> anchorStylesTypeName = 'System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089';
>> anchorType = System.Type.GetType(anchorStylesTypeName);
>> enum = System.Enum.Parse(anchorType, '1')

enum = 

   Top
>> 
>> % That looked good!
>> enum = System.Enum.Parse(anchorType, '2')

enum = 

    Bottom
>>
>> % OK, now we combine them...
>> enum = System.Enum.Parse(anchorType, '3')
??? One or more output arguments not assigned during call to
"_class_dot_paren".
```

The same function works fine when run in C#: Passing "3" to System.Enum.Parse returns "Top, Bottom".